# How can I read Google Vault data using API

Tags: google-api

I want to export archived or legal hold data from Google vault using API. I have checked with Google Vault API but its not allowing to read the data. Is there any API which can perform it?

Comment: Also I found some applications which are able to read and export data from the Google Vault. I am supersized how they are doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Google now has an API for this, which is [here](https://developers.google.com/vault/).

Or are you saying you tried this and it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the vault export api. 
https://developers.google.com/vault/guides/exports